# com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner cannot resolve symbol android

Tags: android, import, sdk

i am trying to import AsyncFacebookRunner class of com.facebook.android package in android studio but it says ,cannot resolve symbol android , any help how to do it will really be great

```
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check with the build version and JRE compile version of your project, also make sure that you have selected the Facebook SDK and included as library in your project.
In Eclipse you can follow these steps to get rid of this problem (if it is the reason).

Right click on your project

Go to properties

Select Android

Then scroll down to the bottom and click Add to include Facebook SDK in your project

Check appropriate "Project Build Target"

Click Apply and then Click OK.

And you are done with the problem

Hope it helps you. :-)